# Subtotal in Excel by Python

Tags: python, excel, subtotal

this is my code without any error

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("D:/write_data.xlsx")

df = xl.parse("Sheet1") 

df['C'] = df['C'].astype(str)

df = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])['C'].count()

df1 = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).sum()

df1.index = [df1.index.get_level_values(0), df1.index.get_level_values(1), ['MFA Total'] * len(df1)]

df.to_excel('D:/pandasout.xlsx')
```

but it did not give the subtotal simple data see below

[image]

please guide me on how I get the subtotal

regard's

Comment: this is my full code      ====    import openpyxl
from spire.xls import *
from spire.common import *
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
xl = pd.ExcelFile("D:/write_data.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1") 
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])['C'].count()
df1 = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).sum()
df1.index = [df1.index.get_level_values(0), df1.index.get_level_values(1), ['MFA Total'] * len(df1)]
df.to_excel('D:/pandasout.xlsx')

Comment: this is the result it did  not give subtotal   --A B C
AA DFG 44
  5
  547
  6
  678
 GFHJF 53
DDDD DFG 56
  778
  8956
  97
 HGF 75
TTTRRRR DDDSD 67
 DDF 75
 DDS 8789
 DFG 5
  6
  78
 HGF 67
 HHHG 789
TTTT DDDSD 567
 DDF 67
 DDS 67
 DFG 789
 GFHJF 890
 GGG 547
 HGF 79
 HHHG 89
YYYUUUUU DDDSD 56
 DDF 897
 DDS 675
 DFG 67
  898
 GFHJF 97
 GGG 75
 HHHG 897

Comment: Dude, add that info in the main question, why put it as comments?